# Editing an inline SVG EKG line, want to use it as a horizontal divider

Tags: html, svg

I actually got something decent here:
http://codepen.io/lastnoob/pen/BozMmw

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 600 300">
  <path d="
         M17.902,114.475h26.949c2.296,0,12.876-10.182,20.063-10.182
        c7.186,0,10.83,10.182,12.576,10.182h18.266l7.187,10.779l7.485-100.91l5.091,114.984l6.887-24.554h24.41
        c3.239,0,14.816-16.769,20.206-16.769s11.08,16.47,13.475,16.47c2.845,0,26.665,0,26.665,0l27.757,0
        c2.296,0,12.875-10.181,20.062-10.181c7.186,0,10.831,10.181,12.577,10.181h18.266l7.187,10.779l7.485-100.91l5.091,114.984
        l6.888-24.555h24.41c3.24,0,14.817-16.768,20.207-16.768s11.079,16.469,13.474,16.469c2.845,0,26.666,0,26.666,0h27.813
        c2.297,0,12.877-10.181,20.063-10.181s10.829,10.181,12.576,10.181h18.265l7.188,10.779l7.485-100.91l5.092,114.984l6.887-24.555
        h24.409c3.238,0,14.816-16.768,20.206-16.768s11.08,16.469,13.476,16.469c2.845,0,26.664,0,26.664,0h27.815
        c2.296,0,12.875-10.181,20.063-10.181c7.187,0,10.829,10.181,12.576,10.181h18.265l7.188,10.779l7.486-100.91l5.091,114.984
        l6.887-24.555h24.409c3.238,0,14.816-16.768,20.206-16.768s11.079,16.469,13.476,16.469c2.846,0,26.664,0,26.664,0"/>

</svg>
```

But since it will be a horizontal divider, I want it to run through the full screen, and I dont really know how to achieve that. Any ideas?

EDIT: I need to extend the path, cause if I do width: 100%; the lines will become too high to use them.
I sort of googled this and that and assembled this path, how would I start making it longer? I dont really understand how to extend the path. I googled but did not find anything useful.

I tried to edit it in illustrator but no success. I made a few more ekg wave spikes, but the dont show up on the codepen.
http://codepen.io/lastnoob/pen/RWGyqX

only those 3 spikes

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `width:100%;` to this svg tag, but be carefull - outlines will become bigger, for me you should consider make this path a little bit "longer".

[Here you have, your forked project:](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYajMV)

Comment: Thanks!
Yeah, I forgot to add... The outlines are too big if I make it width 100%.
To be honest, I sort of googled this and that and assembled this path, how would I start making it longer? I dont really understand how to extend the path.

Comment: I tried to edit it in illustrator but no success. I made a few more ekg wave spikes, but the dont show up on the codepen. http://codepen.io/lastnoob/pen/RWGyqX

only those 3 spikes

Comment: Yea, you should work it out in Illustrator - just add a few more waves.